# Error during publish Unable to remove directory “bin\Debug\app.publish\ ClickOnce

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, clickonce

I am trying to publish my project but when I do it I got an error

I look at here : [Error during publish Unable to remove directory "bin\Debug\app.publish\"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30496766/error-during-publish-unable-to-remove-directory-bin-debug-app-publish)

I try to delete the "bin" file and "obj" file it's not help
I try to delete all my project and start it again on a new location still not work.

When I try to publish another old project it publish a new version fine..

Using visual studio 2019, WPF.

I share a picture of my errors :

[image]

Add the error in text

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Failed to copy file '\\files\Departments\ProgDev\lastVersion\ChooseParametersFormationSorting\ChooseParametersFormationSorting\ChooseParametersFormationSorting\bin\Debug\app.publish\Application Files\ChooseParametersFormationSorting_1_0_0_0\ChooseParametersFormationSorting.exe.config.deploy' to '\\files\~Departments\ProgDev\lastVersion\TestTemp\Application Files\ChooseParametersFormationSorting_1_0_0_0\ChooseParametersFormationSorting.exe.config.deploy'. Unable to add 'Application Files/ChooseParametersFormationSorting_1_0_0_0/ChooseParametersFormationSorting.exe.config.deploy' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'Application Files\ChooseParametersFormationSorting_1_0_0_0\ChooseParametersFormationSorting.exe.config.deploy'.  The system cannot find the path specified.  ChooseParametersFormationSorting        1   
Error       Failed to copy file '\\files\Departments\ProgDev\lastVersion\ChooseParametersFormationSorting\ChooseParametersFormationSorting\ChooseParametersFormationSorting\bin\Debug\app.publish\Application Files\ChooseParametersFormationSorting_1_0_0_0\ChooseParametersFormationSorting.exe.manifest' to '\\files\~Departments\ProgDev\lastVersion\TestTemp\Application Files\ChooseParametersFormationSorting_1_0_0_0\ChooseParametersFormationSorting.exe.manifest'. Unable to add 'Application Files/ChooseParametersFormationSorting_1_0_0_0/ChooseParametersFormationSorting.exe.manifest' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'Application Files\ChooseParametersFormationSorting_1_0_0_0\ChooseParametersFormationSorting.exe.manifest'.  The system cannot find the path specified.  ChooseParametersFormationSorting        1   
Error       Failed to copy file '\\files\Departments\ProgDev\lastVersion\ChooseParametersFormationSorting\ChooseParametersFormationSorting\ChooseParametersFormationSorting\bin\Debug\app.publish\Application Files\ChooseParametersFormationSorting_1_0_0_0\ChooseParametersFormationSorting.exe.deploy' to '\\files\~Departments\ProgDev\lastVersion\TestTemp\Application Files\ChooseParametersFormationSorting_1_0_0_0\ChooseParametersFormationSorting.exe.deploy'. Unable to add 'Application Files/ChooseParametersFormationSorting_1_0_0_0/ChooseParametersFormationSorting.exe.deploy' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'Application Files\ChooseParametersFormationSorting_1_0_0_0\ChooseParametersFormationSorting.exe.deploy'.  The system cannot find the path specified.  ChooseParametersFormationSorting    

1
```

show the target location :

[image]

Tell me if you need any more information..

Adding more information

I found that when I  open a project on my local machine it able to publish it on the file server: `\\files\departments\...`
But when I open my project on my file server it shows this error.
I have to say that more than 2 years all work fine also when I open my project in my file server
What can cause that?

Comment: Is this a multi-targeted project? (I can't see anything from imgur because unfortunately it's blocked on my work PC)

Comment: @MatthewWatson I add my error in text

What you mean my  "multi-targeted project"

Comment: The error message for all 3 errors is quite clear: `The system cannot find the path specified`.

Comment: That `~` in the destination path looks suspicious. (Btw, a multi-targeted project is one that is targeted to multiple frameworks, e.g. .Net Core and .Net Framework. But if you didn't know what it meant, you're unlikely to be using it.)

Comment: @MaciejLos

I add a picture of the location.. Its totally exist

Comment: @MatthewWatson  look on my last comment one up